# A benevolent but cumbersome batch of four sequence puzzles

Tags: riddle, pattern, number-sequence, letter-sequence

Here are four more sequence puzzles. The challenge is to guess the pattern and hence fill in the missing terms. Each "???" denotes exactly one missing term.

1. 6, ???, 5, 8, 4, ???, 7, 3, 4, ???, 4 *(now solved by **March Ho**)*
2. Henry, Lily, Ben, Ned, Natalie, ???, Albert, Simon *(now solved by **KSab**)*
3. 73, 74, 88, 51, 28, 36, 84, 50, 83, 99, ??? *(now solved by **Len**)*
4. 40, 30, 70, 39, 54, 74, 23, ??? *(whoever solves this will get the accepted answer)*

Please let me know whether these are too easy, too hard, or neither! I've tried to arrange them in order of difficulty, but I could be completely wrong with this.

Hint (in riddle form):

> The same thing coming more than once,
>  Sometimes coming once a month.
>  Then the wood on which you eat,
>  Perhaps excelling at what it does.

Comment: are they independent?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Yes, all four are independent.

Comment: Is the title relevant to any of the sequences?

Comment: @xnor No, the title is just a joke. All previous questions of this kind have had titles something like "Another batch of four sequence puzzles", so I thought I may as well do something with the word "batch"! Do you think it's too distracting?

Comment: Could one of the four downvoters please let me know what's wrong with this puzzle so I can improve in the future?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but if I had to guess it is something similar to the days of the spaghetti party debacle where these types of puzzle are becoming too common (though not necessarily to the same degree) and all of the rules defining them are progressing more and more out into left field... just a guess though.

Comment: @Warlord099 Thanks for your feedback. This is the first puzzle of this kind I've made - I think all the others have been by Martin - and the ideas used are no more left-field than those in his puzzles, indeed less so than many of his ideas.

Comment: I just look at the title and see the name [Benedict Cumberbatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict_Cumberbatch).

Comment: @AE Well caught! ;-) As I said to xnor, the title is just a joke and no hint. If you think it's too distracting, I can edit it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sequence 3** is:

> the last 2 digits of the 11 users with the highest rep on puzzling.se. The sequence in the question has been revised as the order has been changing. The missing numbers are shown in bold:
>  ver5: 73, 74, 88, 51, 28, 36, 84, 50, 83, 99, **88**
>  ver4: 73, 74, 88, 51, 28, 36, 84, 83, 50, **20**, 99
>  ver1: 73, 74, 88, **51**, 28, 36, 84, 83, **20**, 99, 50

**Sequence 4** is:

> the atomic numbers for the elements in reverse alphabetical order of the chemical symbols:
>
>  Zr, Zn, Yt, Y, Xe, W, V, **Uut**
>  40, 30, 70, 39, 54, 74, 23, **113**

Comment: Well done! I thought updating the sequence from time to time would count as a hint. You've found yourself ;-)

Comment: Double well-done! I can't upvote more than once, but I can accept.

Answer (score 6):

### Partial answer:

1: Decimal sequence expansion of $10-\pi$

6,**8**,5,8,4,**0**,7,3,4,**6**,4 [OEIS 030644](https://oeis.org/A030644)

Comment: Well done! Any ideas on the other three?

Comment: @randal'thor Not that I could think of in 5 minutes :c

Comment: I thought the first one would be easiest. Keep trying! :-) It's probably too soon for me to give away any hints.

Answer (score 2):

For the second question I believe **Mary** *edit:* *or M'Gann* is a valid answer.
The names begin with first letters of the ordered (though not consecutive) elements of the periodic table, the open spot having to be Magnesium.

Comment: Very good observation. In addition, the first 2 letters of each name match the short form of the elements according to the order in the periodic table (and only the elements with two letters as short form are considered, hence skipping H, B, C, N, O, and F). But the problem is, what name starts with Mg?

Comment: @LaBird At first I was actually thinking that, but I after a brief internet search for names that begin with Mg, I thought that perhaps it was just the two first letters of the elements, I don't know though it does seem like the short form was the asker's intention.

Comment: @LaBird [M'Gann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Martian)?

Comment: Well done! As @LaBird says, the sequence is of names whose first two letters are the codes for successive 2-letter-code elements. I made sure the ??? was in the position corresponding to Magnesium because I couldn't think of a name beginning with Mg ;-)

Comment: Hint: the pattern to the 4th sequence is in the same sort of ballpark.

Comment: @randal'thor - This hint should really be provided in the question instead of the comments.