# A final batch of four sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

This is my seventh (and probably last) batch of sequence puzzles that are nasty and hard to solve; I stress that each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

---

> Sequence 1:
>   RC, NU, RT, RS, PI, ??, AN, PT

---

> Sequence 2:
>   A, ?, D, ?, G, H, J, K, L

---

> Sequence 3:
>   ?, ?, ?, 1, 7, 0, 7, 1, 7, 3, 4, 8, 9, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 9, 1, ?, ?, ...

---

> Sequence 4:
>   O, ?, ?, H, R, A, U, ?, U, E, ?, ?, ?, ...

Comment: "seventh (and probably last)" - mind if I [take over](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/10367/5373) the sequence-puzzle franchise then? ;)

Comment: @Martin - Thanks for all of the sequence puzzles.  They seem to have been prepared with great skill to find a good balance between difficulty and solvability.

Comment: @Len - Thanks!! I feel that this is a good point for stopping. The underlying ideas started to repeat. Perhaps I will have some new ideas two or three months from now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sequence 1:

> TU
>
>  These are the third and fourth letters of each planet in the Solar System.
>
>  ME**RC**URY, VE**NU**S, EA**RT**H, MA**RS**, JU**PI**TER, SA**TU**RN, UR**AN**US, NE**PT**UNE
>  RC, NU, RT, RS, PI, **TU**, AN, PT

Sequence 2:

> S, F
>
>  These are the keys on the home row of a standard QWERTY keyboard.
>
>  A, **S**, D, **F**, G, H, J, K, L

Sequence 3:

> 6, 0, 7, 7, 6
>
>  These are the digits in the decimal expansion of e, shifted down by 1.
>
>  e = 2.718281828459045235360287...
>  digits: **6**, **0**, **7**, 1, 7, 0, 7, 1, 7, 3, 4, 8, 9, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 9, 1, **7**, **6**...

Sequence 4:

> U, E, O, H, R, A
>
>  These are the *second* letters of each day of the week, cycled around.
>
>  M**O**NDAY, T**U**ESDAY, W**E**DNESDAY, T**H**URSDAY, F**R**IDAY, S**A**TURDAY, S**U**NDAY
>  O, **U**, **E**, H, R, A, U, **O**, U, E, **H**, **R**, **A**, ...

Comment: They were pretty easy. :P

Comment: Impressive Joe, how can you be that smart?

Comment: I'm not really smart; the data used to generate the sequences this time around was much more well known than in the previous few.

Comment: unbelievably fast answer! great job!