# Fun Bunch of Letter Sequences

Tags: letter-sequence

Here's a batch of letter sequence puzzles for you. The goal is simple: Figure out which letters go in the blanks. Try it out for yourself and see what you can get.

Puzzle #1
**K, H, D, M, D, _, _** (Solved By *Bailey M*)

Puzzle #2:
**A, B, E, F, G, H, I, J, N, P, _**

Puzzle #3:
**I, E, H, O, I, I, E, I, I, E, _, _** (Solved By *Joe Z.*)

Puzzle #4:
**O, U, E, H, R, _, _** (Solved By *Joe Z.*)

The puzzles are in order from easiest to hardest.

Comment: This seems like it can be easily compared to a number-sequence puzzle, in which answers could be much too broad to be given only 3-5 letters initially.

Comment: Hmm... good point! I'll be sure to add some more.

Comment: I have to admit, number 2 has been harder than all the rest so far.

Comment: C, D, K, L, M, O - just figured it might help people to see, maybe? Still trying to see what might be common in either the present or absent letters...

Comment: Wow! The second one must be pretty difficult!

Comment: Got a hint for the second one?

Comment: Actually, I  forgot what Sequence 2 was too! If nobody gets this soon then I'll accept the answer from Joe Z. for solving 2 sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequence 3:

> The second letters of each ordinal number: first, second, third, fourth, fifth, ...
>
> The letters afterward are **L** and **W**.

Sequence 4:

> The second letters of each day of the week. This one's [appeared on the site before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10530/a-final-batch-of-four-sequence-puzzles).
>
> The letters afterward are **A** and **U**.

More to come later.

Comment: Nice! Good job!

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's start off with the first sequence...

The next two letters are

> **C, M.**

The sequence is

> Metric measurements! Kilometer, Hectometer, Decameter, Meter, Decimeter, Centimeter, Millimeter.

Comment: Good job! That was it!

Comment: Keep on going, I have a feeling that you might get a lot of them!